# Регулярное выражение работает на regex101.com, но не в коде программы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt5

Есть следующий QRegExp:  `QRegExp numberRegExp("^(7|8){1}\d{8,10}$");`

- для проверки телефонного номера в формате +7********** или +8********** (без знака + - указан, чисто для примера), выражение проверенно на https://regex101.com/ - в формате PCRE, однако, при проверке:
  `numberRegExp.exactMatch("some number")` - возвращает false.

Уточню, что в строке - только цифры,ничего лишнего и на вышеуказанном сайте - происходит полное совпадение , т.е, согласно документации - `exactMatch` - должен вернуть true.

Примеры валидных номеров:

> 71234567891,
>
> 81234567891,
>
> 7123456789,
>
> 8123456789,
>
> 712345678,
>
> 812345678

- т.е,префикс состоящий из одной цифры -  7 или 8 и от 8 до 10 цифр, идущих после префикса.

p.s - не смог придумать более подходящего заголовка, буду признателе, за предложенные правки и более подходящие варианты.Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, как вы используете это, чтобы было понятно, в чём ошибка.

Comment: Ну, к сожалению, я не могу указывать реальный номер.

Comment: Зачем указывать реальный номер? Укажите любой номер, который должен проходить и не проходить вашу регулярку.

Comment: Подходящий номер: 71234567891 или  81234567891  - т.е,префикс 7 или 8 и от 8 до 10 цифр.

Comment: Укажите код и примеры в самом вопросе с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1144419/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удвойте символы обратной косой черты:

```
QRegExp numberRegExp("^(7|8)\\d{8,10}$");
QRegExp numberRegExp(R"(^(7|8)\d{8,10}$)");
```

Проблема в том, что ваш строковой литерал содержит текст `^(7|8)d{8,10}$`, где `\` отсутствует по причине того, что не существует строковой управляющей последовательности `\d`, и ядро C++ удаляет символы обратной косой черты из таких невалидных управляющих последовательностей.

Всегда удаляйте из регулярных выражений `{1}`, так как любой неквантифицируемый символ/шаблон находится один раз по умолчанию.

**Подробности**

**Запомните**: регулярные выражения — это *буквальный текст*. Текст можно по-разному задать в коде программы, например, чтение из файла, присвоение значения с помощью [*строковой константы/литерала*](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

В вашем коде используется "обычный строковой литерал". Такие строковые литералы поддерживают *строковые* управляющие последовательности (string escape sequences). Например, текст `2+"2"` в тексте программы можно задать с помощью обычного строкового литерала `"2+\"2\""` с двойными кавычками в качестве разделителей. А ещё можно его задать в виде `"2\x2B\x222\x22"`. Да, в некоторых языках можно использовать разные виды кавычек, чтобы избежать излишнего количества обратных слешей, например, в Python можно написать `'2+"2"'`.

В обычных строковых литералах символ обратной косой черты является "специальным", и чтобы задать в строке сам буквальный символ `\`, нужно его самого "экранировать", т.е. по сути его нужно удвоить. **Именно буквальный символ обратной косой черты является первым символом управляющих последовательностей регулярных выражений.** Управляющие последовательности регулярных выражений (regex escape sequences) — это всем известные `\d`, `\w`, `\s`, `\D`, `\W`, `\S`, `\b`, `\B`, `\\`, `\uXXXX`, `\xNN`, `\+`, `\$`, `\)` и так далее. Да, `\b`, `\uXXXX`, `\xNN` могут быть и одним, и другим типом символов: `"\b"` — это символ BACKSPACE, `"\x08"`, тогда как `"\\b"` — это граница слова. `\uXXXX` и `\xNN` имеют те же значения, будучи заданными как строковые управляющие последовательности и как управляющие последовательности регулярных выражений (символы Юникода).

В C++ и во многих других языках есть возможность задать текстовую переменную с помощью строковых литералов, в которых поддержка строковых управляющих последовательностей отсутствует. Это так называемые ["сырые" строковые литералы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), "raw string literals" ("verbatim string literals" в C# и т.д.). В C++ можно задать такой литрал с помощью префикса `R`. Строковой литерал `R"(\d{3})"` (равный `"\\d{3}"`) хранит в себе текст `\d{3}`, то есть шаблон регулярных выражений для поиска трёх последовательных цифр. Обратите внимание: круглые скобки — это разделители, функциональная часть строкового литерала, они вовсе не задают дополнительной захватывающей подмаски в регулярном выражении.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, ведь - как я понимаю, дополнительный \ - экранирует \d - зачем? Спасибо.

Comment: @BadCatss Минут 40 ушло, проверьте, всё ли понятно.

Comment: да, теперь все предельно ясно.Огромное Вам спасибо. Приношу извинения, что вчера не ответил сразу. Еще раз, спасибо.